# What happens if multiple teammates 3-star an enemy in a war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If your clan is wining like 20-3, and you have 1 attack left, can you put it on a base that someone else has already attacked, and get bonus loot?

How many times can bonus loot be claimed on a single base? Can different team mates attack the same base and all 3 star it and get the loot?

Comment: @Dragonrage what if you both 3 star it?

Comment: As long as you get at least one star on a base, you will get the loot bonus, regardless of how many stars anyone has gotten on the base and how many people have attacked it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done this before, and it if possible to attack an already three starred base and get the loot. When you click on the base, you can see the loot available, and you can attack a certain base as many times as you want as far as I'm aware, because my clan had to attack a base about three times before the three star.